# depth first search using constraints

Tags: python, constraints, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a dfs algorithm to traverse a graph. The goal of this traversal is to find paths. In my case a graph is constructed in which each node represents a city in europe. Nodes are connected to nodes of neighbouring countries (cities in the neighbouring countries). The goal is to find paths throughout europe where the journey starts at a city in a certain country starting with an 'a'. Then move on to a neighbouring country to a city starting with a 'b', then go to a neighbouring country of the last country and move to a city starting with a 'c' etc.

e.g (Amsterdam, Netherlands) --> (Berlin, Germany) --> (Cannes, France) --> etc.

I have constructed a graph in which all cities from a certain country are connected with the cities of the neighbouring countries. In order to find these paths dfs seemed like a logical choice to me. However, I am not sure how to implement certain constraints in this algorithm. For example I do not want to traverse through the graph further if a node (city) does not start with the wanted letter. For example, if I am coming from a city starting with a 'b' I dont want to traverse further when the next node is a 'd'. Also I do not want to visit the same country multiple times. Can someone maybe give me some guidance on how to implement these types of constraints in a dfs model? Below I have a very-bones implementation of dfs and I am wondering where should build these conditions.

```
visited = set()

def dfs(visited, graph, root):
    if root not in visited:
        print(root)
        visited.add(root)        
        for neighbour in graph[root]:
            dfs(visited, graph, root)
```

Thank you for your valuable time in advance!

Kind regards, Jop

Answer (score 0):

The main two things I would reccomend are a helper function to check if a destination is valid and a record of the path you're travelling.

In similar psuedo code, I would recommend something like this:

```
visited = set()
path = [startingDestination]

def validDestination(from, to):
    if countriesNeighborCheck and cityLetterCheck:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def dfs(visited, graph, root, path):
    if root not in visited:
        if validDestination(path[-1], root):
            path.append(root)
            visited.add(root)                   
        for neighbour in graph[root]:
            return dfs(visited, graph, root, path)
```